# How to receive GET request from external source with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm working on a project that allows external users(coming from another source than just my server) to make a GET request to a page on my server, which will then return some JSON encoded data.

For example, say the data (not using Cake, just standard PHP) would be sent to

```
wwww.example.com/handlerequest.php
```

I'd just have something like

```
if(isset($_GET['userRequest'])){
    //do some stuff
    echo $json_encoded_stuff;
}
```

With CakePHP I'd just post the data to something like

```
www.example.com/HandleRequest
```

However, I **do not** want/need a view for this because there is nothing to see. This page is purely for data exchange. Considering this, is there anything special I have to do so that Cake doesn't throw an error because it's expecting a corresponding view? Is this even possible?

Comment: You didnt state your cakephp version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to disable both the layout and view in CakePHP by putting the following line in your controller action:

```
$this->autoRender = false;
```

If you want to disable just the layout, use the following line in your controller action:

```
$this->layout = false;
```

And if you only want to disable the view for this action, use the following line in your controller:

```
$this->render(false);
```

Note that using `$this->layout = false;` and `$this->render(false);` together in your controller action will give you the same results as `$this->autoRender = false;`

Comment: I just thought of something. Do I have to use the view to echo json output?

Comment: no, you can turn off the view and echo from the controller if you want.